# Are negative numbers square-free?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

How would one define whether a number is square-free? For example is -243 a square-free number?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Square free means not divisible by the square of a prime. $n$ is square free if and only if $-n$ is square free.

Comment: negative numbers are always square-free as long as you are in real field. A number is said to be square free if its prime factorization has exactly one prime factor that appears in this factorization.

Comment: So would a negative number be square-free in a number field where K=Q($\alpha$)?

Comment: @ManjoyDas But $6=2 \cdot 3$ is square-free and has *two* prime factors.

Comment: @ManjoyDas That's not true. I suspect you're misquoting the wikipedia definition: "its prime factorization has exactly one factor **for each prime that appears in it**." This is a bit awkwardly phrased - it means that $n$ is square-free iff for each prime $p$ with $p\vert n$ we have $p^2\not\vert n$. Or equivalently, no square (other than $1$) divides $n$. This can be generalized to arbitrary rings: in a ring $R$, an element $a$ is square-free iff there is no non-unit element $b$ with $b^2\vert a$. In the integers negatives can be square-free and everything is vacuously square-free in a field.

Comment: @coffeemath what I meant was that each prime factor will appear once in the factorization.

Comment: @noah i agree with you. my sentence construction was not right. but that was not copied form wiki :D

Comment: @ManjoyDas See jgon's comment. $-6$ is squarefree even though it is negative. All one need say is squarefree means not divisible by the square of a prime.

Comment: @coffeemath in case of negative integers I was thinking in perspective of square root of that integer, i.e the square root cannot exist in $\Bbb{R}$. yeah, that was not right thinking. but single appearance of prime factors can be easy to understand. $-6$ is square free because every prime factor is appearing once. All such definitions are some way more or less equivalent to each other. 'Factors appearing once' is equivalent to 'squares do not divide $n$'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) is, in my opinion, a bit awkwardly phrased. I would phrase it as follows instead:

> In the integers, $z$ is square-free iff no *nontrivial* square divides $z$.

In this context "nontrivial" means "$\not=1$" - after all, $1$ is a square and divides everything. The integers are quite nice, and there are a few equivalent ways we can reformulate this definition, the most common being "no square of a prime divides $z$" (this is what the wikipedia definition is saying in a rather roundabout way); it's a good exercise to prove that this definition is equivalent to the one above.

As to a particular example, we have $$-243=(-1)(81)(3),$$ and so $81\vert -243$. Since $81$ is a nontrivial square in the integers, $-243$ is **not** square-free.

---

The definition above generalizes to arbitrary [**rings**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), with the slight twist that we need a different notion of "nontrivial:"

> In a ring $R$, an element $a$ is square-free iff whenever $b^2\vert a$ the element $b$ has a multiplicative inverse in $R$ (= $b$ is a **unit** in $R$).

In $R=\mathbb{Z}$ the only units are $-1$ and $1$, and so the only squares of units is $1$. So this does generalize the definition above.

Note the absence of primes from the above definition. This is because in rings other than the integers we need not have a good notion of "prime factorization" - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).